# Java Threads - Start()

Tags: java, multithreading

Doing some studying about threads and I'm confused about what the `start()` method in Java threads actually do.

My current understanding is that the start method doesn't immediately start the thread's execution, but instead moves it to a pool of threads waiting for it be picked for execution by the thread scheduler.

Is this correct? I can't seem to find any good resources about what the methods actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly, when a call to `start()` is performed, it just schedules the call to `run()`.  You cannot determinate when the thread will effectively be launched, nor when it will effectively be stopped.

You can find more information in the Java Doc on oracle's website.

Answer (score 2):

> start
>
> public void start() Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java
>   Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread. The result is
>   that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which
>   returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which
>   executes its run method).
>
> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already
>   started. See Also: run(), stop()

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Threads with ThreadPools

A thread is an "unit of execution", code executed on a separate thread runs in parallel with your main programs when you call `start()`

ThreadPools is a mechanism built on top of threads, it allows you to create a **group** of threads which will take care to execute tasks you submit to the ThreadPool queue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. You don't know when this thread will be executed but for sure it is scheduled for running. 
Have a look at the following picture. It explains the lifecycle of a thread: http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/thread.gif

Answer (score 1):

`start` immediately starts the new thread, but by the very nature of threads, there is no guarantee as to when any line of code in that thread will actually execute. It is not appropriate to use the term "thread pool" in this context because the concept of a pool involves resources that are reused between user-requested tasks. A `Thread` instance is hardwired to a single invocation of the `run` method, after which the thread dies.

The thread scheduler is a native OS-level component and is not under the direct control of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Thread.start` it makes a special instarcution to JVM for starting a thread and JVM will taken care of its life cycle.

Comment: The first part of this is just double-talk, unless it refers to some non-existent byte code instruction, and the rest of it is incorrect. The JVM does not implement thread lifecycles itself: the OS does.